# Log4j slf4j to syslog error

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I tried searching for a solution to my error, however unfortunately could not find any result.

After having gotten a simple "Hello World" in slf4j with log4j to work, I wanted to expand it and add an entry into SYSLOG. At this point I encountered an error, which I can't figure out yet.

My Project is basically the maven hello world project, slightly adjusted:

App.java:

```
package xx.xxxx.logging;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        LOGGER.info("Hello Logger!");
        // Marker syslog = MarkerFactory.getMarker("SYSLOG");
        // LOGGER.info(syslog, "Hello Syslog!");
    }
}
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

        <Appenders>
                <File name="FILE" fileName="${java.io.tmpdir}/consumer.log">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
                </File>

                <Console name="STDOUT">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
                </Console>

                <Syslog name="SYSLOG" format="RFC5424" host="localhost" port="514" protocol="UDP" 
                        appName="UAI" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true" newLine="true">
                        <MarkerFilter marker="SYSLOG"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
                </Syslog>
        </Appenders>

        <Loggers>
                <Root level="ALL">
                        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
                        <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
                        <AppenderRef ref="SYSLOG"/>
                </Root>
        </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>xx.xxxx.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>logging-test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>logging-test</name>

  <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <sonar.java.source>${java.version}</sonar.java.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <version.sl4j>1.7.21</version.sl4j>
    <version.sl4j.log4j>2.0.1</version.sl4j.log4j>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${version.sl4j}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${version.sl4j.log4j}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${version.sl4j.log4j}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${version.sl4j.log4j}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>xx.xxxx.logging.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The command 'mvn package' says "BUILD SUCCESS".

Trying to run App.java yields the following error:

```
root@blabla:~/test-syslog/logging-test# java -cp target/logging-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:target/libs/* xx.xxxx.logging.App
2017-12-08 10:45:28,083 ERROR Could not instantiate DatagramSocket to localhost java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.datagramSocketCreate(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.create(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:80)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.createImpl(DatagramSocket.java:337)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:239)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:196)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramOutputStream.<init>(DatagramOutputStream.java:72)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramSocketManager$DatagramSocketManagerFactory.createManager(DatagramSocketManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramSocketManager$DatagramSocketManagerFactory.createManager(DatagramSocketManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:71)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramSocketManager.getSocketManager(DatagramSocketManager.java:65)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.createSocketManager(SocketAppender.java:168)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SyslogAppender.createAppender(SyslogAppender.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:133)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:744)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:683)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:675)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:349)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:150)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:364)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:422)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:146)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:263)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory$PrivateManager.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:98)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:84)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:44)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at xx.xxxx.logging.App.<clinit>(App.java:11)

2017-12-08 10:45:28,185 ERROR catching java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:133)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:744)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:683)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:675)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:349)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:150)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:364)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:422)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:146)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:263)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory$PrivateManager.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:98)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:84)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:44)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at xx.xxxx.logging.App.<clinit>(App.java:11)
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Could not instantiate DatagramSocket to localhost
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramOutputStream.<init>(DatagramOutputStream.java:76)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramSocketManager$DatagramSocketManagerFactory.createManager(DatagramSocketManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramSocketManager$DatagramSocketManagerFactory.createManager(DatagramSocketManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:71)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramSocketManager.getSocketManager(DatagramSocketManager.java:65)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.createSocketManager(SocketAppender.java:168)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SyslogAppender.createAppender(SyslogAppender.java:140)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.datagramSocketCreate(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.create(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:80)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.createImpl(DatagramSocket.java:337)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:239)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:196)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramOutputStream.<init>(DatagramOutputStream.java:72)
        ... 29 more

2017-12-08 10:45:28,556 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SyslogAppender for element Syslog.
2017-12-08 10:45:28,567 ERROR Null object returned for Syslog in Appenders.
2017-12-08 10:45:28,579 ERROR Unable to locate appender SYSLOG for logger
```

Finally, this output is produced:

```
Hello World!
2017-12-08 10:45:28 INFO  App:17 - Hello Logger!
```

Also, writing to file works.

Any leads on how to fix logging to syslog would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the multiple bindings article on the slf4j site?

Comment: I still had an unneccesary import. I removed slf4j-log4j12 to get the multiple bindings error fixed. The rest stays the same unfortunately. I edited the question to not show this little error anymore.